# Converting strings separated by comma in text files to JSON

Tags: python, json, string, parsing

I am having problems converting strings in a text file to JSON format. Right now I have 3 text files, and in each file, there are many rows of object in the file that I would like to convert to JSON format.

The strings are separated by a semicolon, as seen below:

```
mary; 24; female;1993; student
john; 21; male; 1982; student
luke; 22; male; 1988; student
```

How do i convert these to JSON format?

I tried using json.loads() but its not working. Your help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: What is the structure of your JSON? `json.loads()` helps in the case when your data is in a standard JSON format. The file format looks more like of `csv`, `json.loads()` makes no sense here

Comment: What sort of data structure do you want the resulting JSON to represent? A list of strings?

Answer (score 4):

Your text file is not in [JSON](http://json.org/example.html) format, so `json.loads()` won't work. Something like this could help convert it into JSON:

```
$ cat a.txt
mary; 24; female;1993; student
john; 21; male; 1982; student
luke; 22; male; 1988; student

$ cat a.py
import json
arr = []
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      # split around semicolon and then strip spaces from the ends
      fields = map(lambda s: s.strip(), line.split(';'))
      arr.append({
          "name": fields[0],
          "age": int(fields[1]),
          "gender": fields[2],
          "year": int(fields[3]),
          "occupation": fields[4],
      })
print json.dumps(arr, indent=2)

$ python a.py
[
  {
    "gender": "female",
    "age": 24,
    "occupation": "student",
    "name": "mary",
    "year": 1993
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 21,
    "occupation": "student",
    "name": "john",
    "year": 1982
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 22,
    "occupation": "student",
    "name": "luke",
    "year": 1988
  }
]
```

Where I used `json.dumps()` to get a JSON-encoded string from a Python data structure (in this case, a list of dictionaries).

Comment: A *list* of dictionaries :)

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, of course. Switching languages will do that to you :))

Comment: hi @Vlad i tried, but i have this error: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'

Comment: I assumed they were regular `str`ings. I've edited that bit from `str.strip` to `lambda s: s.strip()` which calls `strip()` on whatever it receives. That should work in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since each line of your data appears to contain Character Separated Values, using the Python `csv` module would be a logical way to read it, especially since a `csv.DictReader` will return each row as a dictionary which is extremely convenient when needing to convert that data to JSON format.

```
import csv
import json
import sys

def open_csv(filename, mode='r'):
    """Open a csv file in proper mode depending on Python verion."""
    return(open(filename, mode=mode+'b') if sys.version_info[0] == 2 else
           open(filename, mode=mode, newline=''))

json_objects = []
fields = 'name age gender year occupation'.split()
with open_csv('records.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=fields, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        json_objects.append(row)

print(json.dumps(json_objects))
```

Output:

`[{"gender": "female", "age": "24", "occupation": "student", "name": "mary", "year": "1993"},
  {"gender": "male", "age": "21", "occupation": "student", "name": "john", "year": "1982"},
  {"gender": "male", "age": "22", "occupation": "student", "name": "luke", "year": "1988"}]`